# Is it possible to wrap the whole website in an iframe?

Tags: php, html, laravel, iframe

I have a Laravel site include the whole user authentication(register, sign-in, sign-out, forgot-password, change-password, etc ... ) . It stored in a VPS.

---

My client asked me to wrap it around a framework, so they can just send it to other clients to embed that user authentication in their page. I'm a little confuse when they asked me that. I'm not sure whether or not because I don't know enough about this.

OR

Is that even possible ? If so, what should I look into ? 
I was hoping that someone can sheds a little light on this.

Any hints/suggestion will mean a lot to me.

Comment: I heard that gmail was wrapped in iframe, I dont have source though, need check :(

Comment: So they were right, it is possible.

Comment: What kind of integration are they looking for? You might want more information from them.

Comment: They're looking to share that iframe will the whole user authentication in it to their clients. They want to treat it as a separate module (re-usable). How is it even possible ? The whole thing will need database, and configuration, so on and so forth. It's not a simple video where we can just through the url in the source attribute of an iframe. This is the whole entire website. I'm talking about here.

Comment: So have you tried just embedding a simple `<iframe src="http://www.website.com"></iframe>`? If they just want to embed their website in another while keeping it independent, then a simple iframe will suffice.

Comment: @Bogdan: Thank-you ! I didn't know you can do that. This is cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but you will have to disable the CSRF protection from the routes the form gets submitted too.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what is the benefit of doing that ?

Comment: It won't work unless you disable it, because the form will get submitted from another domain.